# URL linking to collapsible element's child link?

Tags: html, css, uikit

I have a group of accordion cards that collapse on my page, and an example of one is:

```
 <div class="card" style="display:none" >
<div class="card-header" role="tab" id="mainHeading">
  <h5 class="mb-0">
    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#linkTarget" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="linkTarget">
    </a>
  </h5>
</div>
<div id="linkTarget" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mainHeading" data-parent="#accordion">
  <div class="card-body">
    <a id="fileLink" href="https://downloads/testFile.pdf" download="filename">Test File</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if(window.location.href == "/FAQ/fileLink") {
     document.getElementById('fileLink').click()
 }
</script>
```

I currently have it hidden because I don't want it showing but I do want to be able to give someone a URL like

```
www.testSite/FAQ#linkTarget/filename
```

or something like that so that if I give someone the link and they click it or go to it, it acts exactly the same as if they collapsed it and clicked on the download link.

Is there a way I can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can test the window href before any javascript code

```
 if(window.location.href == "www.testSite/FAQ#linkTarget/filename") {
     document.getElementsByClassName('CLASS').click();
   }
```

Change the url to be the one you wanted, and change "CLASS" as the class of the element you want to click when it's the chosen url

Comment: I'm not currently using any javascript, just UiKit, but are you saying to wrap that around so that if they follow the link it will activate the toggle? It my item in the accordian is disabled can I just make it go straight to the download link

Comment: I don't know about UiKit, so tell me (or show me) the line of code that show the acordion please, is that pure css ? or jquery ?

Comment: It's very much like bootstrap. Basically, what I have above it pretty much it. It's a div with a header and when you click on it it expands the body of text beneath it using the targets. I just have it hidden from the user now and I want to use a link to replicate expanding and clicking the link

Comment: May I suggest you to add "UiKit" in the tags of your question? :)

Comment: read my edit, tell me if my english is ok and if understand everything :D

Comment: Yes that does make sense, and thank you. You can see my updates above with the usage but I'm getting a 404 now when I go to the link

Comment: you need to get more knowledge about url design ;) but basically, don't use # if you put some slahes behind. but you can do www.testSite/FAQ?linkTarget=filename